# JPA deleteById() doesn't work when the entity is associated with two other entities

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring Boot v2.5.2

I have `comment` entity that is associated with `user` and `course` ( both bidirectional @ManyToOne )

```
 public class Comment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int commentId;
    @NotBlank(message = "Your comment is empty!")
    private String text;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "course_id")
    private Course course;
 }

public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int courseId;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "course", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Comment> comments;
  }
 
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "inc")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "inc", strategy = "increment")
    private int userId;
    

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Comment> comments;
```

In both associations `comment` is the owner side so I can remove the `comment` and then all associations (for this `comment`) should be removed as well, right? ( it works that way when I have SINGLE association - I mean a one-to-many association between two entities, that's it )

Anyway I can't delete the `comment` using `deleteById(commentId)` method from `JpaRepository`. I enabled the logs for Hibernate and after calling this method I get:

```
    2021-08-03 16:43:35.904 DEBUG 13524 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select comment0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_0_, comment0_.course_id as course_i3_1_0_, comment0_.text as text2_1_0_, comment0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, course1_.course_id as course_i1_4_1_, course1_.description as descript2_4_1_, course1_.price as price3_4_1_, course1_.promotion as promotio4_4_1_, course1_.title as title5_4_1_, categories2_.course_id as course_i2_2_2_, category3_.category_id as category1_2_2_, category3_.category_id as category1_0_3_, category3_.name as name2_0_3_, user4_.user_id as user_id1_5_4_, user4_.name as name2_5_4_ from comments comment0_ left outer join courses course1_ on comment0_.course_id=course1_.course_id left outer join course_category categories2_ on course1_.course_id=categories2_.course_id left outer join categories category3_ on categories2_.category_id=category3_.category_id left outer join users user4_ on comment0_.user_id=user4_.user_id where comment0_.comment_id=?
    2021-08-03 16:43:35.939 DEBUG 13524 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select comments0_.course_id as course_i3_1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_1_, comments0_.course_id as course_i3_1_1_, comments0_.text as text2_1_1_, comments0_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_, user1_.user_id as user_id1_5_2_, user1_.name as name2_5_2_ from comments comments0_ left outer join users user1_ on comments0_.user_id=user1_.user_id where comments0_.course_id=?
```

It even does not throw any error!

Can someone explain why it doesn't work ?

**EDIT**

I Found a solution that makes me much more confused. I decided to break the associations manually (on trial). Look at my code that works:

```
public void deleteComment(Integer commentId) {
        Comment target = repository.findById(commentId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No Comment with given id"));

        Course targetCourse = target.getCourse();
        targetCourse.setComments(null);

        User targetUser = target.getUser();
        targetUser.setComments(null);

        repository.deleteById(commentId);
}
```

(I realize that I shouldn't set comments to null only on a comment set without the one I want to delete but I had a problem with that and this is basically just an attempt)

And my logs from Hibernate:

```
2021-08-03 18:05:14.610 DEBUG 1228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select comment0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_0_, comment0_.course_id as course_i3_1_0_, comment0_.text as text2_1_0_, comment0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, course1_.course_id as course_i1_4_1_, course1_.description as descript2_4_1_, course1_.price as price3_4_1_, course1_.promotion as promotio4_4_1_, course1_.title as title5_4_1_, categories2_.course_id as course_i2_2_2_, category3_.category_id as category1_2_2_, category3_.category_id as category1_0_3_, category3_.name as name2_0_3_, user4_.user_id as user_id1_5_4_, user4_.name as name2_5_4_ from comments comment0_ left outer join courses course1_ on comment0_.course_id=course1_.course_id left outer join course_category categories2_ on course1_.course_id=categories2_.course_id left outer join categories category3_ on categories2_.category_id=category3_.category_id left outer join users user4_ on comment0_.user_id=user4_.user_id where comment0_.comment_id=?
    2021-08-03 18:05:14.655 DEBUG 1228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select comments0_.course_id as course_i3_1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_0_, comments0_.comment_id as comment_1_1_1_, comments0_.course_id as course_i3_1_1_, comments0_.text as text2_1_1_, comments0_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_, user1_.user_id as user_id1_5_2_, user1_.name as name2_5_2_ from comments comments0_ left outer join users user1_ on comments0_.user_id=user1_.user_id where comments0_.course_id=?
    2021-08-03 18:05:14.740 DEBUG 1228 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : delete from comments where comment_id=?
```

Why does it make me more confused? As this should be done automatically (it works like this in my other application where there is a single association - I mentioned about it above). What's more I updated my associations not by owner side. `comment` is owner side so `comment` should be resposnsible for any changes in the assocation, right? ... Somewhere in my reasoning I must be wrong !

Comment: Can you provide a stacktrace of the error?  The code provided is not enough to know why it's not working

Comment: There is no error. The function `deleteById` is called (I know because I can see the hibernate logs) but there is no `delete` statement, only `select`

Comment: How do you know it does not work then? are you committing your transaction? did you check the DB?

Comment: yes i checked the DB, the rows I tried to delete are still in the DB

Comment: are you committing your transaction? and (common mistake) are you looking at the same DB the application is connecting to?

Comment: Yes, it's the same DB :D. I'm using Spring Boot v2.5.2 so I don't need to commit a transaction ... sorry, I should have mentioned what I'm using

Comment: *I don't need to commit a transaction* yes you do

Comment: OK, so I was wrong. I added `@Transactional` annotation. Is it enough ?

Comment: I have edited my question with solution that works

Comment: If you found a solution, do not pollute the question with it.  Write your own answer and mark it as such.

Comment: BTW, your solution might not be desirable as you are leaving behind a bunch of records that are now orphaned.  This will pollute the dB and create headaches down the road.  For a homework assignment or a personal project this might be OK (but you wouldn't want to do this on a production system)

Comment: Yes, you're right that's why I didn't add this as a solution. I have updated my question again to show my reasoning